# Why doesn't lazy evaluation break this code?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

```
add <- function(x) {
  function(y) x + y
}
adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
adders[[1]](10)
```

In the above code Wickham claims in *Advanced R* that because function arguments are lazily evaluated x will be 10 for all of the closures that are created by lapply(1:10, add). But that is not the case after I ran the code in an R session, but even his examples do no demonstrate the breaking of the above code as far as I can tell - why is this?

Comment: Wasn't `lapply` modified by R-core to alter it's argument evaluation sometime after Hadley wrote that?

Comment: Oh, then I am not aware. The book is outdated then. Good thing it's free.

Comment: Yeah, you can see that `x` is read from the environment of the function and varies across the functions... `lapply(adders, function(f) environment(f)$x)`. You can see the behavior he describes with `adders <- list(); for (x in 1:10) adders[[x]] <- function(y) x + y` though

Comment: Yeah, formerly `lapply` would not force the evaluation of the parameter passed to the function. This was changed in R 3.2.0  (https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16093)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the comments already answered the question: `lapply` was modified to have a different behavior than what Wickham wrote at that time.

If you want to dive into it more, here is the R development email thread where it was changed: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-February/070686.html

And here is Hadley Wickham discussing how the example will be fixed in the next version of *Advanced R*: https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/issues/803